# Preserve line breaks when Removing Bookmarked Lines

Tags: replace, notepad++, line-breaks, blank-line, preserve

I have a large text file with several lines and I want to replace several of those lines with a blank line. I used regex to search for certain patterns, marked and bookmarked them, then used:
`Search > Bookmark > Inverse Bookmark` to hopefully highlight those strings I want to blank-replace.

However, I find only `Remove Bookmarked Lines` and `Remove Unmarked Lines`, both of which strip line breaks in the text file.

Is there a way to preserve line breaks while replacing those inverse-bookmarked lines with a blank line?

Sample text (lines `1` and `6` are bookmarked for replacing with an empty/blank line):

```
1 Oroc-Osoc PS
2 Osiao Paglingap Elementary School
3 Osmena  E/S
4 Osmena Elementary School
5 Osmena ES
6 Pablo .M. Conag CS
```

Expected output:

```
1 
2 Osiao Paglingap Elementary School
3 Osmena  E/S
4 Osmena Elementary School
5 Osmena ES
6
```

Comment: Could you show sample lines and expected result?

Comment: Are you wanting to delete the contents of some lines and leave empty lines? So that the total number of lines in the file does not change?

Comment: @AdrianHHH: Yes, that's what I would want. Kindly check sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do any of those alternatives:

**Alternative A)**

1. Copy a space  to the clpiboard with Control+C for example
2. Do: Search => Bookmark => Replace bookmarked lines

If you don't want to leave a space at the beginning of the lines use **Alternative B)**

1. Copy something that cannot repeated on the whole file to the clipboard `<<<EOL>>>` for example.
2. Do: Search => Bookmark => Replace bookmarked lines
3. Replace `<<<EOL>>>` by `\r\n` be sure to mark `extended match`

Comment: Alternative A is good. I could just Trim Trailing Space later on.

Comment: If you use alternative A, you may remove the spaces later with: Search (use regular expression): `^ $`; replace by `nothing`. It is a pity you cannot copy "nothing" to the clipboard in order to do this with less steps.